# yii2 install widget without updating other widgets

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to install 2 amigos map widget using `composer require "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" "*"` but it is updating all widgets. I don't want to update all because everything is working good so i dont want to mess with it. My client Just need map API integrated. I also tried to add API code in composer and update it.

```
"2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" : "*"
```

Then run:

```
composer Update
```

this update whole widgets also.
How can I do Install single widget by ignoring others?

Comment: It's not that you are updating the wrong widget, right?

Comment: take a backup copy of your composer.json. and then write only that widget name (ie: "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" : "*") which you want to update in fresh composer.json file.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the version of packages you are using.

Instead of having in `composer.json` something like:

```
"vendor/package": "*"
```

or

```
"vendor/package": "~1.0"
```

you can do it like that:

```
"vendor/package": "1.3.5"
```

This example locks the package on version 1.3.5 and it will not be updated with `composer update`. The problem of course is you will not get any new features, bug and security fixes that come with updates.

You can check the current version of package you are using by reading the information in the `composer.lock` file.

Comment: so how can I use this code **_composer require "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" "*"_** according to your example? Can you please explain?

Comment: Now I'm not sure now if this is what you need. Is the case here that you want to update this `yii2-google-maps-library` package and there are other packages depending on it and updating `yii2-google-maps-library` updates them as well?